# error "<glog/logging.h> was not included correctly." in including glog in c++ program

Tags: c++, glog

I have an error in including <glog/logging.h>.

My program is (test.cc):

```
#include <glog/logging.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Initialize Google’s logging library.
    google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);

    // ...
    LOG(INFO) << "Found cookies";
}
```

only it!

And my CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.16)
project (myproj VERSION 1.0)

find_package (glog 0.6.0 REQUIRED)

add_executable (myapp test.cc)
target_link_libraries (myapp glog::glog)
```

Also errors are:

```
[build] In file included from /home/smh/Documents/projects/hist/hist/src/hist.cc:4:
[build] /usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:60:4: error: #error <glog/logging.h> was not included correctly. See the documention for how to consume the library.
[build]    60 | #  error <glog/logging.h> was not included correctly. See the documention for how to consume the library.
[build]       |    ^~~~~
[build] In file included from /usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:63,
[build]                  from /home/smh/Documents/projects/hist/hist/src/hist.cc:4:
[build] /usr/local/include/glog/flags.h:45:4: error: #error <glog/flags.h> was not included correctly. See the documention for how to consume the library.
[build]    45 | #  error <glog/flags.h> was not included correctly. See the documention for how to consume the library.
[build]       |    ^~~~~
[build] In file included from /usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:77,
[build]                  from /home/smh/Documents/projects/hist/hist/src/hist.cc:4:
[build] /usr/local/include/glog/log_severity.h:38:4: error: #error <glog/log_severity.h> was not included correctly. See the documention for how to consume the library.
[build]    38 | #  error <glog/log_severity.h> was not included correctly. See the documention for how to consume the library.
[build]       |    ^~~~~
[build] In file included from /usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:78,
[build]                  from /home/smh/Documents/projects/hist/hist/src/hist.cc:4:
[build] /usr/local/include/glog/vlog_is_on.h:71:4: error: #error <glog/vlog_is_on.h> was not included correctly. See the documention for how to consume the library.
[build]    71 | #  error <glog/vlog_is_on.h> was not included correctly. See the documention for how to consume the library.
[build]       |    ^~~~~
[build] In file included from /usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:63,
[build]                  from /home/smh/Documents/projects/hist/hist/src/hist.cc:4:
[build] /usr/local/include/glog/flags.h:105:1: error: ‘GLOG_EXPORT’ does not name a type
[build]   105 | DECLARE_int32(logemaillevel);
[build]       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] /usr/local/include/glog/flags.h:105:1: error: ‘FLAGS_logemaillevel’ has not been declared in ‘fLI’
[build]   105 | DECLARE_int32(logemaillevel);
[build]       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] /usr/local/include/glog/flags.h:106:1: error: ‘GLOG_EXPORT’ does not name a type
[build]   106 | DECLARE_int32(logcleansecs);
[build]       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] /usr/local/include/glog/flags.h:106:1: error: ‘FLAGS_logcleansecs’ has not been declared in ‘fLI’
[build]   106 | DECLARE_int32(logcleansecs);
[build]       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
```

I installed glog from its README in github and all its tests were successful.
[text](https://github.com/google/glog?tab=readme-ov-file#)

And I installed this:
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65588917)

Please help me.

Comment: If your program is "only it!", then it will not work even without glog, because `int main` is missing, and you `add_executable(myapp test.cc)`

Comment: Anyway, cannot repro, this piece of code `#include <glog/logging.h>
int main() { return 0; }` compiles just fine with copy-paste of your `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: Yes, you said correct. But I test it and this error occured again.

Comment: Not reproducible, try to maybe clean your system packages, and install it again. It looks a bit weird that you would first compile and install glog from github repo, and then install it again with apt package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looks like you are using it on Windows, without specify how to use the DLL
or library.
What is causing it is the following section in the header file:

```
#if !defined(GLOG_EXPORT) || !defined(GLOG_NO_EXPORT)
#  error <glog/logging.h> was not included correctly. See the documention for how to consume the library.
#endif
```

In other words: need to add a definition to CMake `add_definitions(-DGLOG_NO_EXPORT)` if you are using glog as a static lib, or `add_definitions(-DGLOG_USE_GLOG_EXPORT)` if glog is a DLL.

If you built glog by yourself, make sure you set the appropriate swiches.

Comment: Apparently `add_definitions` is deprecated; you should use `target_compile_definitions`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947974/file-path-with-cmake-add-definitions

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are building glog library the simplest solution is to compile with

```
#define GLOG_USE_GLOG_EXPORT
```

It will include pltform specific file generated during installation.
This file will define GLOG_EXPORT and GLOG_NO_EXPORT as appropriate.