How to set up seres-solver with visual studio 2022 and vcpkg
I want to use ceres-solver for curve fitting, I am very beginner at this and I don't know where to start, I am using Visual studio 2022 and vcpkg, but I could not make the test program to compile, the errors are C1189 " <glog/logging.h> was not included correctly..., here is the example code (from Google examples at https://ceres-solver.googlesource.com/ceres-solver/+/master/examples/helloworld.cc:
// Ceres Solver - A fast non-linear least squares minimizer
// Copyright 2023 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
// http://ceres-solver.org/
//
// Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
// modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
//
// * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
//   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
// * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
//   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
//   and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
// * Neither the name of Google Inc. nor the names of its contributors may be
//   used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without
//   specific prior written permission.
//
// THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
// AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
// IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
// ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
// LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
// CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
// SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
// INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
// CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
// ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
// POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
//
// Author: keir@google.com (Keir Mierle)
//
// A simple example of using the Ceres minimizer.
//
// Minimize 0.5 (10 - x)^2 using jacobian matrix computed using
// automatic differentiation.
#include "absl/log/initialize.h"
#include "ceres/ceres.h"
// A templated cost functor that implements the residual r = 10 -
// x. The method operator() is templated so that we can then use an
// automatic differentiation wrapper around it to generate its
// derivatives.
struct CostFunctor {
  template <typename T>
  bool operator()(const T* const x, T* residual) const {
    residual[0] = 10.0 - x[0];
    return true;
  }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  absl::InitializeLog();
  // The variable to solve for with its initial value. It will be
  // mutated in place by the solver.
  double x = 0.5;
  const double initial_x = x;
  // Build the problem.
  ceres::Problem problem;
  // Set up the only cost function (also known as residual). This uses
  // auto-differentiation to obtain the derivative (jacobian).
  ceres::CostFunction* cost_function =
      new ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction<CostFunctor, 1, 1>();
  problem.AddResidualBlock(cost_function, nullptr, &x);
  // Run the solver!
  ceres::Solver::Options options;
  options.minimizer_progress_to_stdout = true;
  ceres::Solver::Summary summary;
  ceres::Solve(options, &problem, &summary);
  std::cout << summary.BriefReport() << "\n";
  std::cout << "x : " << initial_x << " -> " << x << "\n";
  return 0;
}

I installed all dependencies and libraries, tried to build vcpkg and the packages several times with static and dynamic modes with several setups that I found on the net, like building from source and including one by one in the linker input option. can any one guide me to a simple way to make the ceres solver working for me.
searched and troubleshoot the vcpkg, and packages, tried static and dynamic linking, tried several examples that I found on the net that claimed to be working but all the time I have the glog and/or ceres related problems, so I think I am not using the right setup, I hope that some one guide me to make it working on Visual Studio 2022.
Update: I already tried the solution in the mentioned question[ [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77912257/error-glog-logging-h-was-not-included-correctly-in-including-glog-in-c-pr][1]], but did not work for me, even the accepted solution is commented as depricated, here is a sample of the compiler output as requested (the output is more than 30000 char accepted here):
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   C1189   #error:  <glog/logging.h> was not included correctly. See the documentation for how to consume the library. ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    60      
    Error (active)  E0840   a template argument list is not allowed in a declaration of a primary template  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\array_selector.h   70              
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\cost_function.h 120     
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\cost_function.h 124         
    Error (active)  E0341   'operator[]' must be a member function  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\fixed_array.h  214             
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "value_type" is undefined    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\fixed_array.h  308     
    Error (active)  E0239   invalid specifier outside a class declaration   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\fixed_array.h  312     
    Error (active)  E0898   nonmember operator requires a parameter with class or enum type ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\fixed_array.h  312     
    Error (active)  E0898   nonmember operator requires a parameter with class or enum type ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\fixed_array.h  329     
    Error (active)  E0757   function "FixedArray" is not a type name    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\fixed_array.h  329     
    Error (active)  E0757   function "FixedArray" is not a type name    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\fixed_array.h  329     
    Error (active)  E0239   invalid specifier outside a class declaration   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\fixed_array.h  333     
    Error (active)  E0898   nonmember operator requires a parameter with class or enum type ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\fixed_array.h  333     
    Error (active)  E0757   function "FixedArray" is not a type name    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\fixed_array.h  333     
    Error (active)  E0757   function "FixedArray" is not a type name    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\fixed_array.h  333     
    Error (active)  E0169   expected a declaration  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\fixed_array.h  337     
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "value_type" is undefined    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\fixed_array.h  366     
    Error (active)  E0169   expected a declaration  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\fixed_array.h  464     
    Error (active)  E0035   #error directive: <glog/flags.h> was not included correctly. See the documentation for how to consume the library.  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\flags.h  45  
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "GLOG_EXPORT" is undefined   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\flags.h  105     
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "GLOG_EXPORT" is undefined   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\flags.h  106     
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "GLOG_EXPORT" is undefined   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\flags.h  111     
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "GLOG_EXPORT" is undefined   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\flags.h  112     
    Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\flags.h  115     
    Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\flags.h  118     
    Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\flags.h  121     
    Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\flags.h  124     
    Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\flags.h  127         
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "GLOG_EXPORT" is undefined   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\flags.h  134     
    Error (active)  E0840   a template argument list is not allowed in a declaration of a primary template  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\integer_sequence_algorithm.h   74      
    Error (active)  E0840   a template argument list is not allowed in a declaration of a primary template  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\integer_sequence_algorithm.h   81      
    Error (active)  E0840   a template argument list is not allowed in a declaration of a primary template  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\integer_sequence_algorithm.h   88      
    Error (active)  E0840   a template argument list is not allowed in a declaration of a primary template  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\integer_sequence_algorithm.h   94      
    Error (active)  E0169   expected a declaration  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\integer_sequence_algorithm.h   288     
    Error (active)  E0135   namespace "ceres" has no member "Jet"   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\jet.h   199     
    Error (active)  E0439   expected a '>'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\jet.h   199     
    Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\jet.h   199     
    Error (active)  E0135   namespace "ceres" has no member "Jet"   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\jet.h   204     
    Error (active)  E0439   expected a '>'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\jet.h   204     
    Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\jet.h   204     
    Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "midpoint"    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\jet.h   505     
    Error (active)  E0842   template parameter "T" is not used in or cannot be deduced from the template argument list of class template "UnderlyingScalar<<error-type>, void>" ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\jet_traits.h   76      
    Error (active)  E0842   constant "N" is not used in or cannot be deduced from the template argument list of class template "UnderlyingScalar<<error-type>, void>"   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\jet_traits.h   76      
    Error (active)  E0864   Jet is not a template   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\jet_traits.h   77      
    Error (active)  E0842   template parameter "T" is not used in or cannot be deduced from the template argument list of class template "Rank<<error-type>, void>" ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\jet_traits.h   122     
    Error (active)  E0842   constant "N" is not used in or cannot be deduced from the template argument list of class template "Rank<<error-type>, void>"   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\jet_traits.h   122     
    Error (active)  E0864   Jet is not a template   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\jet_traits.h   123     
    Error (active)  E0864   Jet is not a template   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\jet_traits.h   142     
    Error (active)  E0169   expected a declaration  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\jet_traits.h   147         
    Error (active)  E0169   expected a declaration  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\jet_traits.h   221     
    Error (active)  E0035   #error directive: <glog/logging.h> was not included correctly. See the documentation for how to consume the library.    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    60      
    Error (active)  E0070   incomplete type "google::GLOG_EXPORT" is not allowed    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    82      
    Error (active)  E0980   call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    83      
    Error (active)  E0067   expected a '}'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    83      
    Error (active)  E0771   'explicit' is not allowed   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    84      
    Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    84      
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    87      
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    90      
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    93      
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    94          
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    104     
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    107         
    Error (active)  E0029   expected an expression  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    690     
    Error (active)  E0067   expected a '}'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    692     
    Error (active)  E0169   expected a declaration  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    694     
    Error (active)  E0169   expected a declaration  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    702     
    Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    830     
    Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    831     
    Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    832     
    Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    833     
    Error (active)  E0169   expected a declaration  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    836     
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "Counter_t" is undefined ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1032        
    Error (active)  E0070   incomplete type "base_logging::GLOG_EXPORT" is not allowed  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1198        
    Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1198        
    Error (active)  E0070   incomplete type "logging::internal::GLOG_NO_EXPORT" is not allowed  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1215        
    Error (active)  E0070   incomplete type "GLOG_EXPORT" is not allowed    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1228        
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LogSeverity" is undefined   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1314        
    Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1319        
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LogSeverity" is undefined   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1319        
    Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1325        
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LogSeverity" is undefined   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1325        
    Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1331        
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LogSeverity" is undefined   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1331        
    Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1335        
    Error (active)  E0169   expected a declaration  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1338        
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1359        
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "int64" is undefined ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1362        
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LogMessageTime" is undefined    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1364        
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1365        
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LogSeverity" is undefined   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1369        
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1369        
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1370        
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1371        
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1372        
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1373        
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LogMessageTime" is undefined    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1374        
    Error (active)  E1670   a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1374        
    Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1376        
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "reason" is undefined    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1393        
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "int64" is undefined ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1396        
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "NUM_SEVERITIES" is undefined    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1396        
    Error (active)  E0757   variable "logging::internal::LogMessageData" is not a type name ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1400        
    Error (active)  E0757   variable "logging::internal::LogMessageData" is not a type name ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1401        
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LogMessageTime" is undefined    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1402        
    Error (active)  E0239   invalid specifier outside a class declaration   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1404        
    Error (active)  E0169   expected a declaration  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1405        
    Error (active)  E0070   incomplete type "GLOG_EXPORT" is not allowed    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1410        
    Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1410        
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LogSeverity" is undefined   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1420        
    Error (active)  E0757   variable "GLOG_EXPORT" is not a type name   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1434        
    Error (active)  E0147   declaration is incompatible with type "std::ostream" (declared at line 231 of "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\iosfwd")   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1434        
    Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1434        
    Error (active)  E0070   incomplete type "GLOG_EXPORT" is not allowed    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1437        
    Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1437        
    Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1484        
    Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1484        
    Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1489        
    Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1489        
    Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1496        
    Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1496        
    Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1505        
    Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1505        
    Error (active)  E0070   incomplete type "GLOG_EXPORT" is not allowed    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1513        
    Error (active)  E0029   expected an expression  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1514        
    Error (active)  E0067   expected a '}'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1515        
    Error (active)  E0239   invalid specifier outside a class declaration   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1520        
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LogSeverity" is undefined   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1520        
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LogMessageTime" is undefined    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1522        
    Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1525        
    Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1526        
    Error (active)  E0239   invalid specifier outside a class declaration   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1643        
    Error (active)  E0239   invalid specifier outside a class declaration   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1646        
    Error (active)  E0239   invalid specifier outside a class declaration   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1651        
    Error (active)  E0145   function "base::Flush" may not be initialized   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1651        
    Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1740        
    Error (active)  E0169   expected a declaration  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\logging.h    1742        
    Error (active)  E0035   #error directive: <glog/log_severity.h> was not included correctly. See the documentation for how to consume the library.   ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\log_severity.h   38      
    Error (active)  E0144   a value of type "ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction<CostFunctor, 1, 1> *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "ceres::CostFunction *"   ceresTest   D:\GitHub\ceresTest\main.cpp    63      
    Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction<CostFunctor, kNumResiduals, Ns...>::AutoDiffCostFunction [with CostFunctor=CostFunctor, kNumResiduals=1, Ns=<1>]" matches the argument list ceresTest   D:\GitHub\ceresTest\main.cpp    63      
    Error (active)  E0864   _Iter_value_t is not a template ceresTest   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\numeric   96      
    Error (active)  E0864   _Enable_if_execution_policy_t is not a template ceresTest   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\numeric   102     
    Error (active)  E0864   _Enable_if_execution_policy_t is not a template ceresTest   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\numeric   105     
    Error (active)  E0864   _Enable_if_execution_policy_t is not a template ceresTest   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\numeric   111             
    Error (active)  E0864   ParameterDims is not a template ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\parameter_dims.h   119     
    Error (active)  E0169   expected a declaration  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\internal\parameter_dims.h   121     
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LinearSolverType" is undefined  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\solver.h    327     
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "SPARSE_NORMAL_CHOLESKY" is undefined    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\solver.h    331     
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LinearSolverType" is undefined  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\solver.h    930     
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LinearSolverType" is undefined  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\solver.h    942     
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LinearSolverType" is undefined  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\types.h 452     
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LinearSolverType" is undefined  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\types.h 454     
    Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LinearSolverType" is undefined  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\ceres\types.h 525     
    
    Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\vlog_is_on.h 130     
    Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  ceresTest   C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\glog\vlog_is_on.h 130 


Please show the full compiler output

@AlanBirtles, I added the compiler output up to the limit  of 30000 chars allowed here.

That's not the compiler output, that's the error window and mostly is intellisense errors, not compiler errors

What exactly did you try to fix your problem?

@AlanBirtles, I tried to follow on the ceres website on how to install, I installed and reinstalled vcpkg, and all ceres dependenceies (I can provide screenshot or list of vcpkg installed libs, I tried to look here in stackoverflow, some questions are  about linux system, I tried to use static and dynamic linking, I even copied the libraries to my project folder, if there is any way to make it work even with manual build it will be great.

How did you add the GLOG_USE_GLOG_EXPORT/GLOG_EXPORT/GLOG_NO_EXPORT defines?

@AlanBirtles, I added them in my code before the include of <glog/logging.h>  and <ceres/ceres.h>  to be processed before the include happens.

here are the libraries installed in my vcpkg folder: abseil:x64-windows-static
ceres:x64-windows-static
ceres[cxsparse]:x64-windows-static
ceres[eigensparse]:x64-windows-static
ceres[lapack]:x64-windows-static
ceres[schur]:x64-windows-static
ceres[suitesparse]:x64-windows-static
ceres[tools]:x64-windows-static
egl-registry:x64-windows-static

eigen3:x64-windows-static
expat:x64-windows-static
gflags:x64-windows-static
gklib:x64-windows-static
glog:x64-windows-static
lapack-reference:x64-windows-static
lapack-reference[blas-select]:x64-windows-static
lapack:x64-windows-static
libjpeg-turbo:x64-windows-static
liblzma:x64-windows-static
libpng:x64-windows-static
metis:x64-windows-static

nanosvg:x64-windows-static
nlopt:x64-windows-static
opengl-registry:x64-windows-static
opengl:x64-windows-static
pcre2:x64-windows-static
pcre2[jit]:x64-windows-static
pcre2[platform-default-features]:x64-windows-st...
suitesparse:x64-windows-static
tiff:x64-windows-static
tiff[jpeg]:x64-windows-static
tiff[lzma]:x64-windows-static
tiff[zip]:x64-windows-static
vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows
vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows
vcpkg-gfortran:x64-windows-static
zlib:x64-windows-static

The build output: Build started at 08:42 AM...
1>------ Build started: Project: ceresTest, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.cpp
1>D:\GitHub\ceresTest\main.cpp(38,10): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'absl/log/initialize.h': No such file or directory
1>Done building project "ceresTest.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 08:42 AM and took 00.677 seconds ==========

Please [edit] clarifications into the question. This is the reason that we ask for the actual compiler output, it shows a completely different error of not being able to find absl/log/initialize.h, the glog error is likely from a previous compile. Have you installed the abseil library and enabled it in your project?

After some days of searching I found a solution to my case, unfortunately I can not share it because the question is closed, I used vs2022 cmake project with adding explicitly the vcpkg tool chain. vcpkg worked in manifest mode but not in classic mode.

If you [edit] the question so that its in an answerable state then it can be reopened
